# Is it possible to use the Google Drive software to sync a file and maintain a common share URL?

Tags: sync, google-drive

I have a file that I modify on a regular basis that is synced to my Google Drive folder on my computer. I've set this file to be shared publicly and shared the link to the file with others. Unfortunately, this URL is specific to this version of the file.

How can I continue to sync my file to Google drive, yet maintain an non-changing URL that I can share with others so that they always have a link to the most recent version of my file?

I have seen this [tutorial](http://blogger-hints-and-tips.blogspot.com/2013/08/replace-google-drive-file-with-new-version.html), which indicates I can do this via the web UI and uploading a new file via the Manage Revisions dialog. These extra steps are not what I'm seeking to do.

I am seeking to perform these actions all via the desktop client and not interact with the web UI at all (except, perhaps for initially setting up the shared link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [niutech has answered this on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11054878/is-is-possible-to-get-a-permanent-url-to-a-file-uploaded-to-google-drive)

> Yes, you can get a permalink to any file hosted on Google Drive in a
>   public folder. 
>   [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aYhE.png]
>   Just note the folderID: Google Drive folder ID and
>   paste it to the following URL:
>
> ```
> http://googledrive.com/host/<folderID>/<filename>
> ```